# How to punctuate a long sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> The discipline by which an enterprise in any industry assesses, controls, exploits, finance, and monitors risk from all sources for the purpose of increasing the enterprise's short and long term value to its stakeholders.

I can understand the latter half of the sentence from "for the purpose of ... to its stakeholders." For the first half, does it mean an enterprise risk from all of these aspects? How should I cut the sentence so that I can understand it more easily?

Comment: It's not a complete sentence. It lacks a verb that complements "discipline."

Comment: It's not a complete sentence, but a 'heavy' noun phrase.

Comment: @Robusto No, that's a complete sentence. What we lack is a preceding sentence. It's just a repetition for the rhetorical effect. For example: _I'm going to talk about a discipline. The discipline by which_... and so on.

Comment: @user8314628 You should have indicated whether you example was from a dictionary definition or from some text.

Comment: @Mv Log It is just a sentence from a slide. There's no preceding sentence there as well.

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books?id=L1CVGVxHGpcC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=%22The+discipline+by+which+an+enterprise+in+any+industry+assesses%22&source=bl&ots=FxUqP28YJI&sig=rQ3OnRVVptPWloIcrpQ9pD9sVQE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6w-GJirLWAhUzb5oKHWubCckQ6AEIMDAC

Comment: @MvLog: If it's a sentence, what verb governs the subject?

Comment: @Robusto _assesses, controls, exploits, finance, and monitors_, **an enterprise in any industry** is the subject.

Comment: @MvLog: Nope. "The discipline" is the subject.

Comment: @Robusto I meant the subject of the relative clause. _The discipline_ doesn't seem to be a subject, it's just a repetition of the preceding complement. _I'm going to talk about a discipline (The discipline) by which_... and so on.

Comment: @Robusto Or maybe it's [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/verbless-sentence-scesis-onomaton-1692589)

Comment: @MvLog: Why would you even talk about that? The claim here is that the text is a sentence and I maintain it's not. You claimed it is yet you can't find a verb to bind everything together *as a single sentence*. The reason you can't is because one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as long as it is, it's still just a sentence fragment.  This looks like a definition of some term, like "fiduciary responsibility" in which case the complete sentence would be:

> **"Fiduciary responsibility" is defined as** [the discipline by which ...]

The other possibility is that "discipline" is the subject, in which case the verb and any direct object are missing.

> [The discipline by which ...] **is lacking in this organization**.

This is probably why you find the sentence confusing.  Once you see the complete context, hopefully, it makes more sense.

Comment: That makes sense. So risk is a verb describing an enterprise. But the main sentence lacks a verb to describe the discipline, isn't it?

Comment: @user8314628  Yep, although I think it's more likely the subject is missing.  Dictionaries often present word meanings in this way, since the subject is implied.  "[X is] the way the enterprise measures risk and increases profits."